# can we use recursion for this case in multidimensional arrays to push new values

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, recursion, multidimensional-array

how to push the the new value in each arrays `container` if the fruits container < the target we wanted,

example:

```
- we should push new fruits in those 2d arrays:
 - List item
 - the  maximun "apple" in container must has 3 fruits,
more than it, we should push to new array/index  in next 2d array container
 - the  maximun "mango" in container must has 2 fruits,
more than it, we should push to new array/index in next 2d array container
 - the  maximun "stawberry" in container must has 4 next fruits,
more than it, we should push to new array/index in next 2d array container
```

```js
const stawberry = x => {
     return x.filter(el => el === "stawberry").length;
  }

const apple = x => {
     return x.filter(el => el === "apple").length;
  }

const mango = x => {
     return x.filter(el => el === "mango").length;
  }

const fruits = kindOfFruits => {

  if(kindOfFruits.length === 0){
    return [];
  } else if(stawberry(kindOfFruits[0]) === 0 ){
    kindOfFruits[0].push("NEW STAWBERRY");
  }
  return kindOfFruits.concat((fruits(kindOfFruits.slice(1))));
}

const container = [
  ["apple", "apple", "banana", "mango", "stawberry", "banana", "banana"],
  ["banana", "mango", "stawberry", "stawberry"],
  ["apple", "mango", "mango"]
];

console.log(fruits(container));
```

I want the RESULT like this:

```
[
  ["apple", "apple", "banana", "mango", "stawberry", "banana", "banana", "apple", "mango", "stawberry ", "stawberry", "stawberry"],
  ["banana", "mango", "stawberry", "stawberry", "apple", "apple" , "stawberry"],
  ["apple", "mango", "mango"]
];
```

NOTE:
it doest matter if the fruits not sorting when we push , as long the fruits in container same like we wanted to push :D,

the data container already made, and we just need to put fruits in each containers 2d arrays ,
like the rules above I said

I hope my questions make sense, sorry if don't

Comment: the result It want is on the below,

Comment: I think I should update, I just want use apple only, sorry if I added the new , let me edit

Comment: that data already made, and we just need each container from the rules I said, to push again if each `container` less than target fruits we wanted to put them in `container`

Comment: @NinaScholz I hope it makes sense , thanks for your help:D

Comment: @NinaScholz my recursions code on above is wrong, that is why I want to know how to fix that and get some help,
to main case is just we wanted to push the fruits on rules each `container`

Comment: @NinaScholz I check the length of zero because I was slice the arrays , by recursions

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a lot of gap in your question, there is not any target defined or how many kind "fruit" will be in the container and etc.

As I understand from your question, you want to full filled the 2nd dimension array upon the target. So I skecth some piece of code:

```
    var appleTarget = 5;
    var mangoTarget = 7;
    var strawberryTarget = 12;
    var kindOfFruit = ["apple", "mango", "strawberry"];

    function fruitCount(subFruitContainer, fruit)
    {
        return subFruitContainer.filter(el => el === fruit).length;
    }

    function insertFruit(dimension , fruit)
    {
        dimension.push(fruit);
    }

    function stableContainer(fruitContainer)
    {
        var selectedTarget;
        kindOfFruit.forEach(function(fruitKind) {
            fruitContainer.forEach(function(dimension){
                if(fruitKind == "apple") selectedTarget = appleTarget;
                else if(fruitKind == "mango") selectedTarget = mangoTarget;
                else if(fruitKind == "strawberry")  selectedTarget = strawberryTarget;
                else selectedTarget = 0;
                var fruitKindCount = fruitCount(dimension, fruitKind);
                if(fruitKindCount < selectedTarget) 
                {
                    for(var i = selectedTarget-fruitKindCount; i > 0; i--) 
                    {
                        insertFruit(dimension, fruitKind);
                    }
                }
            });
        });

        console.log("stabled container");
        console.log(fruitContainer);
    }

    var container = [
        ["apple", "apple", "banana", "mango", "stawberry", "banana", "banana"],
        ["banana", "mango", "stawberry", "stawberry"],
        ["apple", "mango", "mango"]
    ];

    stableContainer(container);
```

Comment: the functions u make you fill the targets on each arrays 2 dimensions, I want to just fills the first arrays 2 days, and if the fruits in array 0 less than target , we push, and if already push, If already fill what push and already full on the arr 0, we push the next index 2d arrays again

Answer (score 0):

An approach by looking for same items as the new item, count and test against the wanted maximum and push either to the actual index (if count is smaller) or to the next item (if at start or greater than the wanted count).

this approach takes an array with items and add each item by looking for the `container` situation.

```js
function addFruit(fruit) {
    const 
        addFruits = (s, v) => s + +(v === fruit),
        max = { apple: 3, mango: 2, stawberry: 4, default: Infinity };

    var i = 0;

    while (i < container.length) {
        if (container[i].reduce(addFruits, 0) < (max[fruit] || max.default)) break;
        i++;
    }
    container[i] = container[i] || [];
    container[i].push(fruit);
}


var data = ["apple", "apple", "mango", "stawberry", "banana", "mango", "stawberry", "banana", "apple", "apple", "stawberry", "banana", "apple", "mango", "stawberry", "stawberry", "stawberry", "banana", "stawberry"],
    container = [];

data.forEach(addFruit);

console.log(container);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: what should be added to the given data? where do you get the additional items from?

Comment: the obj of max you put is already correct, and we chat each first array in 2d arrays if not greater or less with value max, so we push is less that it, and if it already fill and our max values still have, we put next arrays in 2d arrays again